# What is the equivalent of a prime number in $\Bbb Z$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, complex-numbers, prime-numbers

The conventional concept of primes really has value only for the natural numbers, as given integers, any prime $p$ can be broken down into $(1,p) $ and $(-1,-p)$. And when one includes irrationals, the concept breaks down even further.

My question is, are there numbers in $\Bbb Z$ that can only be divided by 1 and themselves? Or is the concept not extendable beyond $\Bbb N$?

Comment: therein primes have atmost four divisors

Comment: Actually, the standard interpretation of "prime number" generalizes to [irreducible elements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_element) while a certain property of prime numbers generalizes to [prime elements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_element).

Comment: There *is* a number in $\mathbb{Z}$ that can only be divided by $1$ and by itself, namely $-1$.  If you allow the "by itself" to be redundant, then $1$ is another such number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The concept of [primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_element#Definition) exists in any commutative ring $R$.  In general, a prime is any element $p$ of the ring that is non-zero, non-invertible and has the property that for all $a, b \in R$, if $p \mid ab$ then $p \mid a$ or $p \mid b$.

In the case of $\mathbb{Z}$, the primes are the natural numbers $p$ that are normally called prime (i.e., $2, 3, 5, 7, 11, \ldots$) as well as their negations ($-2, -3, -5, -7, -11, \ldots$).

Comment: So would $1+3i$ be prime in $\Bbb Z$?

Comment: $1 + 3i$ is not an element of $\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Oh my. I made a massive mistake, I meant $\Bbb C$

Comment: @script8man It's best to ask a new question if there's something else you'd like to know.  Edits should be for clarification but not to ask a different question.

Comment: @script8man Feel free to link to your new question from here with a comment if you like.

Comment: I'm unable to ask for another hour

Comment: @script8man Looking for primes in $\Bbb{C}$ is same as looking at primes in $\Bbb{R}$ (pointless) however looking at $\Bbb{Z}[i]$ there are the [Gaussian primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integer#Gaussian_primes)

Comment: @script8man Primes must be non-zero and non-invertible, so there aren't any primes in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2585026/what-are-the-equivalents-of-primes-in-bbb-c

Answer (score 0):

Another generalization is to consider numbers of the form $p^{2^n}$ instead of primes.  Multiplication is a bijection between positive integers and finite sets of such numbers (whereas with primes this is a bijection to finite multisets instead).  Now include $-1$ as well, and multiplication is a bijection between the finite sets and $\mathbb{Z}$.