# What are the equivalents of primes in $\Bbb C$?

Tags: complex-numbers, prime-numbers

Note: I asked a similar question earlier about integers, and I was advised to create a new one for the question of the complex plane

The conventional concept of primes really has value only for the natural numbers, as given $\Bbb Z$, any prime $p$ can be broken down into $(1,p)(1,p)$ and $(−1,−p)(−1,−p)$. And when one includes irrationals, the concept breaks down even further.

My question is, are there numbers in $\Bbb C$ that can only be divided by 1 and themselves? Or is the concept not extendable beyond ℕ?

Comment: Gaussian prime https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integer#Gaussian_primes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a complex number be prime?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1702779/can-a-complex-number-be-prime)

Answer (score 4):

The concept can be extended in a variety of ways, but not to $\mathbb{C}$ in an interesting way. (*)

You are trying to describe [irreducibles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_element), those numbers which cannot be factored (except by using [units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_(ring_theory)) like $1,-1$).  There are many [rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)) (like $\mathbb{Z}$) and [semigroups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semigroup) (like $\mathbb{N}$) where this is an interesting concept.

Here is my favorite, easy, example: $2\mathbb{N}=\{2,4,6,8,\ldots\}$, the set of even natural numbers.  $6$ is irreducible, because the only way to factor it is $2\cdot 3$, which uses an "illegal" number, i.e. one not in the semigroup.  Hence $6$ is irreducible.  By similar logic, $10$ is irreducible.  It turns out that $30$ is also irreducible, because $30=2\cdot 3\cdot 5$, and there's only one $2$ available, so no matter how you factor $30$, only one of the two factors will get a $2$.

Hence, in this semigroup, you get two different factorizations of $60$ into irreducibles: $$6\cdot 10=2\cdot 30$$

You may have noticed that I didn't call these "primes", rather irreducibles.  The reason is that the two terms are used to mean slightly different things: a [prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_element) $p$ is a number that satisfies $$ \text{ if } p|xy\text{ then } p|x\text{ or } p|y$$

It turns out that every prime is always irreducible, but not every irreducible is prime.  In the example $2\mathbb{N}$ above, $2$ divides $2\cdot 30$, but $2$ does not divide either $6$ or $10$ (because if $2|6$, then $6=2\cdot 3$ would be a factorization in $2\mathbb{N}$, which it isn't).  Hence $2$ is irreducible but not prime in this semigroup.

(*)   The reason is that in $\mathbb{C}$, every nonzero number is a unit, so there are no irreducibles.

Answer (score 3):

There are no primes in $\mathbb{C}$ because every non-zero element of $\mathbb{C}$ is invertible, so every non-zero element of $\mathbb{C}$ divides every other.

This is reflected in the definition of a [prime element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_element#Definition) for a commutative ring, which requires that prime elements be non-zero and non-invertible.

Comment: It's not that the notion doesn't make sense, but that it's degenerate; the notion is trivial.

Comment: @Hurkyl That is a more precise way of putting it, though I would not have thought that the original wording was so objectionable as to merit a downvote.

Comment: I could understand if that's the reason; but I do not actually know why your post got downvoted.

Comment: Mine got downvoted too, so it seems that somebody's grumpy.